# How To Retrieve The Performance Of A Security On Specific Timeframe?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]

I am trying to retrieve the performance metrics for the timeframes listed in the photo. Just the percentage value for 1 Week, 1 Month, 3 Months, & 6 Months.